# Git - Permission Denied (publickey) when pulling from remote server

Tags: git, ssh

I am running WSL2 on top of Windows. Locally, inside WSL2, I am able to push/pull to the remote Github repository without trouble.

When I SSH into a remote server via that same SSH key, I connect successfully. However, once on that remote server and I try to run `git pull`, I receive the `permission denied (publickey)` error. Even with `ssh -t git@github.com` I receive the error.

I tried adjusting my config file in `~./ssh` with:

```
Host *
    AddKeysToAgent yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host abc.theserver.com
    User theuser
    ForwardAgent yes
```

My public key is inside the `authorized_keys` file on the remote server. And I can SSH in successfully, so I'm not sure why git is rejecting the key

Output for `ssh -Tv git@github.com` is:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.112.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/theuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version babeld-f06bbde2
debug1: no match: babeld-f06bbde2
debug1: Authenticating to github.com:22 as 'git'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/theuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/theuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/theuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/theuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/theuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: What's the output of `ssh -Tv git@github.com` when you run it from the remote server?

Comment: @JimRedmond I've added the output to the question. I should note that a separate public/private keypair of mine is not on the remote server. I was under the impression I that the forwarding agent would allow me to use my private key that is local since I already connected to the remote server successfully via SSH

Answer (score 0):

Based on the output of `ssh -Tv git@github.com`, it looks like the Ubuntu server isn't using the forwarded agent credentials. That suggests that one or more of the following are true:

1. `ssh-agent` isn't running on your WSL2 instance
2. The WSL2 config doesn't permit agent forwarding
3. The Ubuntu server doesn't permit agent forwarding

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/using-ssh-agent-forwarding#troubleshooting-ssh-agent-forwarding has some suggestions for how to detect and correct these potential issues (though you may need to have a polite conversation with the Ubuntu server's admins).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I will look into this and get back to you.